# Force NAnt to build references during Cruise Control build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cruisecontrol.net, nant

We have a project I'll call Project1, which is an ASP.NET Web Application that references another project I'll call Project2. In VS, Project1 references Project2 via a 'Project Reference' in the solution. Both projects are setup as separate projects in Cruise Control and build as normal via NAnt. We now have a requirement that when Project1 is built, it also builds Project2 and grabs the resulting DLL. Currently, the build of Project1 simply grabs the latest DLL from Project2 from whenever it was last built, which is incorrect.

How can we achieve this?

Regards,

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to make two NAnt calls for Project1's CCNET configuration. The first call to compile Project1 and second to compile Project2 using the newly compiled Project1 DLLs.

Comment: Marked yours as answer as it was first post :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [project trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger). Put it in the ccnet config for Project2 so it will build whenever Project1 builds.

Comment: I went with this solution and it worked in building both projects, however it turns out this didn't correct the problem. We have had to put a delete task in to clear the obj directories. Even when we deleted the bin directory and rebuilt both projects we were getting old DLLs. Deleting the obj directory fixed it